# what`s different between source and just execute a file?

Tags: linux, shell

When we edit the ~/.bashrc file,we must execute

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to make the change work in current environment.

why not make it executable and just run it?

```
chmod +x ~/.bashrc
~/.bashrc
```

When I looked into the bashrc file,looks like they are all just commands,but the file is not executable,so how it works?

somewhere I see this:

> source is a bash shell built-in command that executes the content of
>   the file passed as argument

What is the significance of its existence?just execute the command are more Intuitive.
Does it mean when I do:

```
export username=mike
```

the variable is valid in the sub-shell,but not current shell,but if we use source command ,it will be valid in the current shell?

Comment: When `source` is used the commands, including variable assignments, are run in the **current** shell. If the script is executed (without `source`) the commands are run in a **new** shell.

Comment: See the Bash manual on [Bourne shell built-ins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) where the command is listed as `.` (second entry, after `:`), but the entry mentions that it is identical to `source`.  (History: the C shell uses `source`; the Bourne and POSIX shells use `.` for the same job.  Bash imported the C shell operation for reasons which remain unclear to me.)